# Xresources and colors

Tags: terminal, color-scheme, xorg

When seeking xterminal themes, one can find plenty with just a google search.

Here is a one:

*background: rgb:00/00/00

*foreground: rgb:a8/a8/a8

*color0:     rgb:00/00/00

*color1:     rgb:a8/00/00

*color2:     rgb:00/a8/00

*color3:     rgb:a8/54/00

*color4:     rgb:00/00/a8

*color5:     rgb:a8/00/a8

*color6:     rgb:00/a8/a8

*color7:     rgb:a8/a8/a8

*color8:     rgb:54/50/54
*color9:     rgb:f8/54/50
*color10:    rgb:50/fc/50
*color11:    rgb:f8/fc/50
*color12:    rgb:50/54/f8
*color13:    rgb:f8/54/f8
*color14:    rgb:50/fc/f8
*color15:    rgb:f8/fc/f8

So the background and foreground colors seem legitimate, however, what are the colors ranging from 0 to 15 for ? I can suppose programs like ls use them, since changing those 16 colors affect 'ls --color' output.

I'd be grateful if one could enlight my view of what those colors are or are for and how they affect colorschemes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The names `color0` through `color15` are xterm resource names, which correspond to the ANSI (0-7) and aixterm-like (8-15) colors set using escape sequences.  The resource names are listed in the xterm [manual page](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html), and the escape sequences in the [XTerm Control Sequences](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html).  Various applications use these escape sequences, either via a library such as [ncurses](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.html), or hardcoded.  (GNU ls is in between -- it does not use the regular terminal database, but has its own *different* one which is a nuisance).

They are *resources* so that users can easily customize the color palette. For instance, the [exact shade of *blue*](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#dont_like_blue) used has been a matter of dispute.

There "could" be names for the resources for colors 16-255, except that there is a limit of 400 resource names in the X libraries (so xterm does not provide those names -- it grew past that limit in [2004](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.log.html#xterm_188)).